# Laravel выборка всех значений со значениям из промежуточной таблицы

Tags: laravel, querybuilder

Вообщем встала такая проблема. Есть страница где мы выбираем категории, связь Many To Many, после этого на странице изменения, мы должны вывести все категории выбранные и все категории не выбранные, как это сделать?

Comment: whereHas имеете ввиду ? или with('название связи') и далее has

Comment: Уже сделал спасибо Решение with(['modelName' => functuion($query) {              
 $query->where() or $query->with()->where() or $query->with(['modelName' function($queryName) {                                                                                                       }  $queryName->with() or $query->where() ]}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Решение:

```
    $table = Example::where(['id' => $id])
             ->join('table', 'example.table_id', '=', 'table.id')
             ->first();
```